# Post Private Message to Selected User

Tags: 7

I've built an iOS app on the Drupal iOS SDK. That said, I want my logged in user to be able to send a message to another Drupal user. Right now, I'm successfully pulling received Private Messages from my services endpoint - but does anyone know how I would go about successfully posting a message to a specific user id? Are there any tutorials out there for this?

Comment: Are you using this SDK then => http://kylebrowning.github.io/drupal-ios-sdk/? How is Private Messages implemented/configured on the Drupal side?

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis I am, yes! Right now I've turned the Message type into a services view that displays Private Messages, and I'm pulling the received messages to the app that way. I'm just not sure how I should go about posting a new message to a specific UID... e.g. post a message to uid 42 so that it's displayed in their inbox.

Comment: So, this is the https://www.drupal.org/project/message module you are using?

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis Correct!

Comment: Reading the docs quickly, I don't see a method for creating Entities (that would be a Message). You can create Nodes, Comments and Users, but not Entities. You can probably work around this situation inside Drupal, but you would need to leave the Message module aside. Would that be an option?

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis I was thinking that... I could just create a content type for "Messages" and use that? And then use DIOSNode... But once I'm logged in for example as say user 1, can I post a "message" to user 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a rough sketch of how you could go about this:

iOS Side: Add a node using [DIOSNode's add](https://github.com/kylebrowning/drupal-ios-sdk/wiki/drupal-ios-sdk-2.0#add)

Drupal Side:

1. Create you own custom content type, e.g. CustomMessage, with a UserID field for collecting the target user of each message. This could be a simple text field, or an Entity Reference field, single or multi-valued.
2. Create a Services View that will use a user's UID as a contextual filter, in order to display all messages targeted at a specific user.

Comment: Ur welcome, good luck!

Comment: Quick question: I've just implemented this and realized - if I create a text field to grab the targeted user id (e.g. in my app, uid is posted to my created field, 'targetuser'), do I use targetuser as the contextual filter? Uid and targetuser aren't connected? I essentially want my view to say: "Only display messages with this user's user id in the field targetuser" - is this doable? Am I missing something lol?

Comment: Hey there, do you still need feedback for this? Maybe you could start a new thread, makes more sense, right?

Comment: Hey Stefanos! YES please :) See: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198288/filter-view-content-by-data-in-text-field

Comment: Nevermind - I figured it out your way : ) Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds good. Sorry, I am following passively at the moment, not in front of a computer. Very happy to hear, nevertheless!