# Filter view content by data in text field

Tags: 7, views

I've created a text field on a custom content type. The text field is called "targetUser" on my content type "message".

targetUser is meant to collect the uid of a user that a current app user is sending a message to. **E.g.** If user 1 is sending a message to user 7, the number "7" will post to the targetUser field.

I want to create a view that ONLY displays "messages" with the targetUser number that matches the logged in user's uid, so that they may ONLY see messages meant for them.

**I essentially want my view to say:** "Only display messages with this user's uid in the field targetuser" - is this doable? Hope I explained this well enough.

Comment: Looks like you are using nodes to allow users to send messages to other users, which is fine. But just wondering, did you consider using [Private Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) for this?

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes I did - but Drupal iOS SDK doesn't allow me to post to an entity; only retrieve data from an entity (building an iOS app). Hence, the use of nodes to send messages :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this ended up being MUCH easier than anticipated. I simply created a "targetuser" text field underneath of my custom Messages content type.

Then, I created a Content View, and added the following filters:

**CONTEXTUAL FILTER**

***Content:*** targetuser

Then click on the above filter, and:

**WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL**

Provide Default Value

and select: **User ID from logged in user**

This way, the targetuser id always matches that of the user logged in. Voila, only messages for logged in user appear.

Comment: Nice one @Brittany. I guess I was over thinking things. Will make a mental note on this trick.

Answer (score 2):

> targetUser is meant to collect the uid of a user that a current app
>   user is sending a message to

IMO the better approach would be to make targetUser an entity reference field.

- Download and install the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module

  - In content type Message fields, add a new field with **Entity Reference** and a widget of **Auto complete (tag style)**

For example: I named mine lalala (click picture below to enlarge)

[image]

- For Target Type, select **User**
- Number of Values: **Unlimited** (as you could send a message to multiple users)

[image]

Then add or edit a message node and start typing user name, you will see the name in the drop down, select it and save.

Use a comma `,` to add other user account.

[image]

### In your view

- contextual filter of Logged in User id (uid)
- add a **relationship** of lalala Referenc**ed** Entity

  - If not, try Referenc**ing** entity, but if my memory is correct it's Referenc**ed**

**Result:** you should get a view of all the nodes where the logged in user was referenced.

---

> The autocomplete only allows by username, and not uid. E.g. posting 47
>   into this field isn't allowed?

Create a new USER view.

1) click on +Add

2) Select Entity Reference

3) Remove user:name and add user:uid

4) click on settings and checkmark uid (if you don't do this step, it won't let you save the view)

[image]

Go to your Content Type Messages manage fields and edit your entity reference field.

- At the bottom check mark ✓ Render Views filters as select list
- Change to mode to View and select your view.

[image]

> Also, "logged in user id (uid)" isn't an option? Just (author) User:
>   Uid ?

You will need to create a CONTENT view and then add:

- Relationship of Referenced User
- Now since you have a relationship User: Uid becomes available as contextual filter

[image]

[image]

Comment: The autocomplete only allows by username, and not uid. E.g. posting 47 into this field isn't allowed?

Comment: Also, "logged in user id (uid)" isn't an option? Just (author) User: Uid ?

Comment: @Brittany updated answer.

Comment: After doing all of the above, for some reason no nodes are shown when I implement 'Entity Referenced from field targetUser' under contextual filters? And I'm still unable to post the UID to the targetUser field :/

Comment: @Brittany it will show empty when you edit the view, but the nodes should show up when you visit the page. `I'm still unable to post the UID to the targetUser field` Darn, looks like this is a flaw of the auto-complete, it forces to user to select rather than just type =(

Comment: Nodes don't show up when I visit the page either :/

Comment: @Brittany maybe because the entity reference is not set in node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38483/discussion-between-brittany-and-no-sssweat).